# using Exomisere structure to modify an MVStore

Tags: intellij-idea, project-structure

i am currently trying to figure out how i can append my own data to the MVStore that the Exomiser uses. https://github.com/exomiser/Exomiser.git

So the MVStore is accessed like

MVMap alleleMap = mvStore.openMap("alleles");

So i tried to rebuild the Allelekey and Property classes but there are so much dependencies that it takes like forever. Can i somehow access the Exomiser structures? Like import them as a library in Intellij or something? How do i do that?

Thank you for your time. All help is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Dennis

Comment: MVMap < AlleleKey, AlleleProperties >  alleleMap = mvStore.openMap("alleles");

Comment: Thats what i meant